# Matlab: Extracting the line segments from the Canny Edge Detector

Tags: matlab, lines, edge-detection

Is there a way to get all the line segments from the built in Canny edge detector in Matlab?

edgeImage = edge(image, 'canny')  <-- does Matlab have method to make the line segments in edgeImage accessible?

Comment: I don't think it does - but you can get the threshold values with `[edgeIm t]=edge(img, 'canny');`, which you could feed into the `contour` method; that, in turn, would allow you to get the line segments.

Comment: You can get (not necessarily straight-line) connected components with bwlabel, or you could look for linear structures using a hough transform.  I'm not sure there's an accepted standard way to extract line segments from Canny.

Comment: have a look at `bwtraceboundary`. It does not extract line segments but if the lines are pretty straight, what you can do is observe the slope and at points where the slope changes drastically, you can say that second line segment is starting.